# Log scale plot with limited range on Plank radiation equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot Planck radiation equation as shown below. When I use Mathematica it plots well, but when I try to do it with Python, I couldn't get it right. It basically does not plot below ~ 1.0 um wavelength. Please, see attached images and codes. If you can help, it would be very appreciable. Thank you in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy as np

h = 6.626e-34
c = 2.9979e+8
k = 1.38e-23

def planck(wav, T):
    a = 2.0*3.14*h*c**2
    b = h*c/(wav*1e3*1e-9*k*T)
    intensity = a/ ( ((wav*1e3*1e-9)**5) * (np.exp(b) - 1.0) )*1e-6
    return intensity

wavelengths = np.logspace(1e-2, 1e2, 1e4, endpoint=False) 

intensity310 = planck(wavelengths, 310.)
intensity3000 = planck(wavelengths, 3000.)
intensity5800 = planck(wavelengths, 5800.)
intensity15000 = planck(wavelengths, 15000.)

plt.plot(wavelengths, intensity310, 'k-') # 5000K Black line
plt.plot(wavelengths, intensity3000, 'r-') # 5000K green line
plt.plot(wavelengths, intensity5800, 'y-') # 6000K blue line
plt.plot(wavelengths, intensity15000, 'b-') # 7000K Red line
pyplot.xscale('log')
pyplot.yscale('log')
pylab.xlim([1e-2,1e2])
pylab.ylim([1,1e10])
plt.show()
```

A plot using Python
[image: A plot using Python]

A plot using Mathematica

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your usage of `np.logspace()`. If you want values from `1e-2` to `1e2` you should call the function with arguments `-2` and `2` respectively i.e. `np.logspace(-2, 2, 1e4)`. Besides, if you want to make a log-scaled plot you can use `pyplot.loglog()` function. There is no need to import `pylab`. See the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

h = 6.626e-34
c = 2.9979e+8
k = 1.38e-23

def planck(wav, T):
    a = 2.0*3.14*h*c**2
    b = h*c/(wav*1e3*1e-9*k*T)
    intensity = a/ ( ((wav*1e3*1e-9)**5) * (np.exp(b) - 1.0) )*1e-6
    return intensity

wavelengths = np.logspace(-2, 2, 1e4, endpoint=False) 

intensity310 = planck(wavelengths, 310.)
intensity3000 = planck(wavelengths, 3000.)
intensity5800 = planck(wavelengths, 5800.)
intensity15000 = planck(wavelengths, 15000.)

plt.loglog(wavelengths, intensity310, 'k-') # 5000K Black line
plt.loglog(wavelengths, intensity3000, 'r-') # 5000K green line
plt.loglog(wavelengths, intensity5800, 'y-') # 6000K blue line
plt.loglog(wavelengths, intensity15000, 'b-') # 7000K Red line
plt.xlim([1e-2,1e2])
plt.ylim([1,1e10])
plt.show()
```

I get the following plot:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Dear Amit Singh, This is what I am looking for. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.